# Checking the ASCII value of different characters

Tags: c#, if-statement, char, ascii, counter

I need to make a program which gets an random char and checks his ASCII value (int).

for example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first character");

char num1 = int.char(Console.ReadLine());

if((character) >= 65 && (character) <= 90 && (character) >= 97 && (character) <= 122)
{
    letters += 1;
}
```

This program checks the value like it is a number and if I enter the letter **F** for example it wont add 1 to the letters counter.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Perhaps if((character >= 65 && character <= 90) || (character >= 97 && character <= 122)). But regular expressions are easier.

Comment: @JesperMygind I tried to do                                                                      character <= 'A' && character <= 'z'

Comment: @oerkelens I need to get an password that has to have an bigger or equal amount of letters then numbers

Comment: Well, I never would have guessed that from the question as you formulated it. Simple tip: do _not_ read that password character by character, simply read the whole password and do your validations on the whole thing.

Comment: Apart from your if-statement being wrong, as others pointed out, what is `(character)`? You are assigning a value to `num1` and then you are checking a totally different variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first character");
char num1 = int.char(Console.ReadLine());
if(((character) >= 65 && (character) <= 90) || ((character) >= 97 && (character) <= 122))
{
    letters += 1;
}
```

You made a small mistake in your AND-OR logic.

Answer (score -2):

You can try the following code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter how many characters your password will have");
        int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int letters = 0;
        int numbers = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the character");
            char character = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z' || character >= 'a' && character <= 'z')
            {
                letters += 1;
            }
            if(character >= '0' && (int)character <= '9')
            {
                numbers += 1;
            }
            if (character <= 'A' && character >= 'Z' || character <= 'a' && character >= 'z' || character <= '0' && (int)character >= '9')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("you have entered invalid character");
            }
        }
        if(letters >= numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The password has " + num1 + " characters and its legal");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The password has " + num1 + " characters and it is illegal");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The answer ⬆️⬆️⬆️

Comment: Your use of `ReadLine()` is going to be problematic.  What if they enter more than one character?...

Comment: If you want to read one letter/key at a time use `Console.ReadKey` not `Console.ReadLine`. Also use `int.TryParse` over `int.Parse`.

Comment: It is nice that you answer you own question, but this answer does not actually answer the question. As it stands now, your "question" reads like a riddle, giving some small random parts of a program, and you present the complete program as an answer.